# How to stop sending Invoice email to Customer in Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, database, magento-enterprise

I am using magento 1.9.2 version.

The customer place an order (Choose Payment Method - Cash On Delivery).

And when I Generate Invoice, the customer is notified by invoice email.

I do not want to send invoice email to customer before deliver his order.

I want to send his invoice after successful order delivery.

How can I stop sending invoice email to customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable invoice email from `system > configuration > sales > sales email > invoice`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin **System > Configuration**

Under the tab **Sales** you will find **sales email**

[image]

Click on Sales Email go to invoice tab set **Enable** to **No**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Disable invoice email from

```
system > configuration > sales > sales email > invoice.
```

That's it !